# I crashed sample code from Apple

Tags: ios

I was discovering some code from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html) which basically displays photos from our albums.

So this apps, when we choose all photos from our device, shows in grid every image and video. Every cell has size `(80, 80)`, but the problem is when we increase this size (e.g. in storyboard) to let's say `(120, 120)`. Know when we scroll very fast to the bottom of collection view (assuming that we have more than 200 photos in our phone, which is quite popular case) the app crashes without stopping on breakpoint in AppDelegate, but it prints this:

> objc[68113]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x1171ea998) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x11700c880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Am I doing something wrong? ;)

Comment: Add all exceptions breakpoint instead of placing a random one in AppDelegate. Why do you expect it to stop in AppDelegate anyways? There appears to be some conflict in your installed Xcode and SDK anyways judging from the warnings

Comment: With which iOS version are you trying this ?

Comment: Oh so I noticed that I have different version of sdk and iOS! About breakpoint, I mean that when your app crashes it stops in AppDelegate if you didn't add breakpoint

Comment: That's why you need to add "All Exceptions breakpoint" so that it will stop precisely at the line which is causing the trouble

Comment: Yep I understand, but despite that I added All exceptions breakpoint it didn't stop

Comment: You can also view [My previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829187/how-to-compare-phasset-to-uiimage/38830110#38830110) on how to load and display infinite Image assets in a TableView/CollectionView using Photos Framework

Comment: Thanks, I will check that!

Comment: Also see [This SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520499/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-frameworks), especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39582284/4029561)